# Trying to solve model using pyomo and bonmin. Model not passed to solver correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, solver, pyomo

I wish to use Pyomo and Bonmin in an operations research seminar concerning the "Extended Supporting Hyperplane Algorithm" from Kronqvist. I wish to use bonmin to compare the performance of the algorithm. First I want to test, whether Bonmin is installed correctly and it is working in together with pyomo, so I modeled an example from the paper mentioned above. It is a convex problem, so bonmin should be able to solve it.

My OS is Windows 7, so I installed Bonmin using Cygwin and added it to my PATh. I did not notice any error message during the installation. For Programming I am using Anaconda with Jupyter Notebook.

I am currently reading through the pyomos documentation, but did not have any luck so far.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
import numpy
import scipy

# Konkretes Optimierungsproblem

model = ConcreteModel(name = "Example 1")

model.x1 = Var(bounds=(1,20), within=Reals)
model.x2 = Var(bounds=(1,20), within=Integers)

model.obj = Objective(expr=(-1)*model.x1-model.x2)

model.g1 = Constraint(expr=0.15*((model.x1 - 8)**2)+0.1*((model.x2 - 6)**2)+0.025*exp(model.x1)*((model.x2)**(-2))-5<=0)
model.g2 = Constraint(expr=(model.x1)**(-1) + (model.x2)**(-1) - (model.x1)**(-0.5) * (model.x2) ** (-0.5)+4<=0)
model.l1 = Constraint(expr=2 * (model.x1) - 3 * (model.x2) -2<=0)

#Just some output to analze the generated model

print(model)
dir(model)
print(model.g2.expr)
model.x1 = 5
print(value(model.x1))

opt = SolverFactory('bonmin')
#opt.options['bonmin.algorithm'] = 'Bonmin'
print('using Bonmin')
# Set Options for solver.
opt.options['bonmin.solution_limit'] = '1'
opt.options['bonmin.time_limit'] = 1800
results = opt.solve(model)
results.write()
```

These are the results:

```
using Bonmin
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
    model=Example 1;
        message from solver=bonmin\x3a Infeasible problem
# ==========================================================
# = Solver Results                                         =
# ==========================================================
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Problem Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Problem: 
- Lower bound: -inf
  Upper bound: inf
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 0
  Number of variables: 0
  Sense: unknown
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solver Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solver: 
- Status: warning
  Message: bonmin\x3a Infeasible problem
  Termination condition: infeasible
  Id: 220
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.16000056266784668
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solution Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0
```

As you can see, the model ist not transferred to the solver correctly, since according to the solver the problem has neither constraints nor variables.

Could the problem be the warning stauts of the Solver meaning it is not installed correctly or is this due to the problem being infeasible?

Edit: As suggested by Bethany Nicholson in the comments, I added the option `tee=tree` in the code, which lead to the following output

```
using Bonmin
Bonmin 1.8.7 using Cbc 2.10.0 and Ipopt 3.12.12
bonmin: bonmin.solution_limit=1
bonmin.time_limit=1800
bonmin.solution_limit=1
bonmin.time_limit=1800


******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

NLP0012I 
              Num      Status      Obj             It       time                 Location
NLP0014I             1      INFEAS 4.0986776       27 0.031
NLP0014I             2      INFEAS 4.0986776       27 0.015
Cbc0006I The LP relaxation is infeasible or too expensive

    "Finished"
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
    model=Example 1;
        message from solver=bonmin\x3a Infeasible problem
# ==========================================================
# = Solver Results                                         =
# ==========================================================
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Problem Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Problem: 
- Lower bound: -inf
  Upper bound: inf
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 0
  Number of variables: 0
  Sense: unknown
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solver Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solver: 
- Status: warning
  Message: bonmin\x3a Infeasible problem
  Termination condition: infeasible
  Id: 220
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.23000025749206543
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solution Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0
```

Edit 2: I have tried other simple problems. While the problem is solved correctly (x1=4, x2=2, minvalue=-10) by Bonmin, its output states that the problems passed to the solver has no constraints, when it clearly has five (even though four might be interpreted as bounds). Furthermore, the output still appears a little strange to me. Why does it state "number of solutions = 0"? (I am still not through with the complete documentation of pyomo, maybe I just have to set additional parameters)
Here is the linear problem:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
import numpy
import scipy

model = ConcreteModel(name = "Linear problem")

model.x1 = Var(domain = Reals)
model.x2 = Var(domain = Reals)

model.obj = Objective(expr=-1*(2*model.x1+model.x2))

model.l1 = Constraint(expr=model.x1>=0)
model.l2 = Constraint(expr=model.x2>=0)
model.l3 = Constraint(expr=model.x1<=4)
model.l4 = Constraint(expr=model.x2<=4)
model.l5 = Constraint(expr=model.x1+model.x2<=6)
model.pprint()
2 Var Declarations
    x1 : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
    x2 : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize : - (2*x1 + x2)

5 Constraint Declarations
    l1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
        None :   0.0 :   x1 :  +Inf :   True
    l2 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
        None :   0.0 :   x2 :  +Inf :   True
    l3 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
        None :  -Inf :   x1 :   4.0 :   True
    l4 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
        None :  -Inf :   x2 :   4.0 :   True
    l5 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body    : Upper : Active
        None :  -Inf : x1 + x2 :   6.0 :   True

8 Declarations: x1 x2 obj l1 l2 l3 l4 l5

opt = SolverFactory('bonmin')
opt.options['bonmin.solution_limit'] = '1'
opt.options['bonmin.time_limit'] = 1800
results = opt.solve(model, tee = True)
results.write()

Bonmin 1.8.7 using Cbc 2.10.0 and Ipopt 3.12.12
bonmin: bonmin.solution_limit=1
bonmin.time_limit=1800
bonmin.solution_limit=1
bonmin.time_limit=1800

Cbc3007W No integer variables - nothing to do

******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

NLP0012I 
              Num      Status      Obj             It       time                 Location
NLP0014I             1         OPT -10        4 0
Cbc3007W No integer variables - nothing to do

    "Finished"
# ==========================================================
# = Solver Results                                         =
# ==========================================================
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Problem Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Problem: 
- Lower bound: -inf
  Upper bound: inf
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 0
  Number of variables: 2
  Sense: unknown
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solver Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Message: bonmin\x3a Optimal
  Termination condition: optimal
  Id: 3
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.20000028610229492
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solution Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0
```

I am sorry if I appear to be spamming my post with code. Just thought it would be helpful, since I think this indicated that the problem lies with the solver rather than the modelling with pyomo.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your model, at a minimum you have a degrees of freedom issue as you've declared 2 variables and 3 constraints. You can see more detailed solver output by adding the `tee=True` option to your call to `solve`.

Comment: All Constraints are inequations. Therefore, the degrees of freedom should not be a problem, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a meeting with my tutor yesterday. I actually overlooked an error in the model, which made it infeasible. Bonmin solves the problem correctly, but the output still looks strange (e.g. model possesses no constraints). He does understand the somewhat strange output of the solver either, however, he said I should not concern myself with it any further.

I deeply apologize for doing such a stupid mistake. Hopefully no one spent much time thinking on this question (except me of course).

Comment: "I deeply apologize for doing such a stupid mistake" How could you know? Anyway, everyone makes mistakes. Come back next time!

Comment: There are some issues with the results object (see [link](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/1033)).